# How to get snapShot if user have sign in with email or gmail in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to get the snapShot of user provider If the user have sign in with Email show this. But if user have sign in with Gmail then show this.

**code from what I get so far:**

```
           StreamBuilder<User?>(
                stream: authBloc.currentUser,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Text(
                        'Oops somethings went wrong');
                          }    
                        body: ...(
                         snapshot.data!.providerData.contains("email")
                              ? Text("You have sign in with Email")
                                //Show this if user have sign In with Email provider   
                                                    
                              : Text("You have sign in with Gmail"),
                                //Show this if user have sign In with Gmail provider                     
                                ),
                              ),
                             }
                          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User.providerData is type of `List<UserInfo>`, and each UserInfo class has a getter `providerId`. For sure, that's what you're looking for too.

So what you can do is

```dart
bool isEmailPasswordUser = snapshot.data!.providerData.any(
    (userInfo) => userInfo.providerId == "password",
);

bool isGoogleAuthUser = snapshot.data!.providerData.any(
    (userInfo) => userInfo.providerId == "google.com",
);
```

And based on these bools, show your widgets.

Hope this helps :)